# Cannot boot, laptop screen doesn't work, may have broken grub

Tags: boot, grub2, multiple-monitors

My laptop's built in screen has been out of commission for awhile, which usually isn't a problem since I use an external monitor, but the GRUB/BIOS menus don't appear on the external monitor.

I was trying to get it to display on the second monitor, and changed the kernel parameter to `nomodeset` via Grub Customizer, since I had seen it suggested and figured it probably would be easy to change back if it didn't help. I also set the grub menu to automatically open on start up, and do the default boot after ten seconds. Well, it actually made the problem many magnitudes worse, and now my laptop is unusable.

I turn it on, still can't see the menu, and it doesn't automatically boot after 10 seconds like it should. I've tried inserting my Ubuntu live CD, hoping that maybe something would happen. Nothing happened.

I'm not sure if I screwed up and broke grub, or if it's a different problem, but either way it's a big problem. Is there any way that I can fix this without being able to see what I'm doing? I considered using my brother's computer to burn a rescue disc, but I'm not sure if I'd be able to boot one up with my computer in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

That's weird you don't see bios/grub menu's on the monitor.  Do you have the laptop lid open? Also, it would help if we knew what laptop model it was.  Usually you can boot to a live cd even in the state that it's in.  Just plug in a monitor with the computer lid closed(but open just enough so you can turn it on) so you get video so you can a least know what your doing, then boot to Ubuntu live cd.  I don't really know what to do from there, hope this might help you.

EDIT:

Try this link may help you:
  http://ubuntu.aspcode.net/view/635400140124705175542464/cant-boot-up-ubuntu-after-changing-grub-file-with-nomodeset

EDIT:

Ok so it looks like you might have to press a combination of keys to get to see the bios.  Try doing FN and one of the F keys(usually the one for the display has a little monitor on the key).  Also, try locating the lock magnet on your laptop lid and put a magnet to trick it into thinking it's closed, but not really(so you'll have access to the keyboard, mouse, power button).

Comment: It's an HP, I don't remember exactly what model though, and there's nothing on the outside that specifies that. I do have the laptop lid open. I will try that though, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: When I close the laptop it goes straight to sleep. I'm not really sure how I'd use it with the lid closed.

Comment: It stays running when I close it like that, but it still doesn't use the external monitor. For some reason it doesn't like using other monitors until the OS boots. If I knew how many lines down all of the options used in that link are, I could maybe pull it off without the screen. Any chance you'd be willing to help me out in that area? If the menu is consistent between computers anyways.

Comment: Try using a combination of a FN key and F key(F5 F4 etc.) look for the one with a little monitor/screen on the key.

Comment: Yes, I can help you with it.  Just need to know what version of Ubuntu you have.

Comment: Sorry I never got back to you, I forgot that I had added that last comment. I wound up taking it in and getting the screen fixed. It came back in a worse state (boot issue wise, the screen had been repaired properly), so I'm guessing they tried to do something with it and failed? Good thing I use disc encryption aha, who know's what they may have been up to. I just re-installed Ubuntu when I got it back, so the problem has been sorted.

Comment: Ok, great.  If you want you can mark my answer as correct or make your own answer for yourself.  Or just leave it blank.